# Embedded Mongo : Session not supported by Mongo Cluster Issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am working on unit testing using embedded mongo. It is able to connect to mongo at the random port but on running the test I am getting error of - com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am getting an error : com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster on running my application through embedded mongo

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are testing mongo transactions on a standalone mongo instance. Mongo supports transactions only for a replica set since the transactions depend on the existence of the oplog. So for your unit tests you need to deploy replica set. Note that there is no need to deploy replica set with 3 nodes, 1 node is enough.